# What happens if a slapped player plays a card before playing a Slap

Tags: exploding-kittens, exploding-kittens-party-pack

Say Alice plays a Double Slap targeting Bob.

Say Bob plays a card, which accepts the Double Slap. Then, Bob plays a Double Slap targeting Chuck, ending their first turn. Bob then plays a Skip for their second turn.

Would Chuck be able to play a Double Slap to pass on the slaps to Darlene x4, or do they have to take the double turn since the Double Slap was not the last card played?

Answer (score 3):

Double Slap reads:

> End your turn and make a player take any other turn you have plus two more.

When you play a Slap card, your turn ends and all your remaining turns are transferred to the slapped player. That means the second player illegally played Skip when it wasn't their turn in your example.

What should have happened:

1. Alice plays a Double Slap targeting Bob. Play transfers to Bob, which must play 2 turns (as per the text on the card).
2. Bob plays a card (thus taking a turn instead of responding to the Slap with a Nope or another Slap).
3. Bob plays a Double Slap targeting Chuck. Play transfers to Chuck, which must play Bob's remaining turn plus two more, for a total of 3 (as per the text on the card).
4. Chuck responds with a Double Slap targeting Darlene. Just like playing Nope, this is played out of turn. Play transfers to Darlene, which must play the 3 turns Chuck would have had to play plus two more, for a total of 5 (as per the example in the rules).